# Django: How to retrieve in an AJAX POST request the value of two different variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send to my Django view two values from two different dropdowns but it doesn't work. Only the first dropdown value is sent to the view.

Let's say I have the following view:

```
def MyView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:

        result_1 = request.POST.get('d1')
        print(result_1)
        result_2 = request.POST.get('d2')
        print(result_2)
```

And this is the html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dropdownChange () {
    var selectedRegion = $(".toChange option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/myApp/templates/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'d1': selectedRegion},
            }
    }); 
}
$(".toChange").change(dropdownChange);
</script>

  <select name="d1" class="toChange">
    <option val="1"> 1 </option>
    <option val="2"> 2 </option> 
  </select>

 <select name="d2">
    <option val="3"> 3 </option>
    <option val="4"> 4 </option> 
  </select>
```

When the dropdown d1 faces a change, I want both d1 and d2 values to be sent to my view. The value of d1 is properly captured but d2 (so result_2) shows "[]". How can I capture the two variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add it in the data variable:

```
var selectedRegion = $(".toChange option:selected").val();
var selectedRegion2 = $("select[name=d2] option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/myApp/templates/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'d1': selectedRegion, 'd2': selectedRegion2},           
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately print(result_2) still returns an empty list. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you selected any value in the 2nd select box?

Comment: Ok, it now seems to work, even though it's not exactly as I expected since in my code, the change of dropdown 1 changes dropdown 2, but it's the old value of d2 that gets sent to my view, not the new one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great! You could post a separate question for that case. I didn't see the code for that in this question

Comment: Yes, I'll investigate it on my end first and if I get stuck I'll post a new question. Thanks!